# HTML/PHP select form having value selected before

Tags: php

I have prepared a simple .php document that allows user to pick a value to be printed and then posts it to php script that prints it. Here is the code i used:

```
<?php
  echo('<form method="post">
    Select value:
    <select type="integer" name="val" value= "">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="display"/>
    </form>');
  $val = $_POST['val'];
  echo($val);
?>
```

however, I have two problems with it:

1. When first opened it displays a naughty line "Notice: Undefined index: val in C:\ ...\test.php on line 12". How do I fix it?
2. When I press display button, printing script works fine, but list value comes back to 1 instead of the number selected.

This is my first post on StackOverflow, sorry if I broke any rules, I just couldn't find the solution. 
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: `<select>` does not have a `type="integer"` ;-) it doesn't have a "type" to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `<select>` does not have a `type="integer"` (it doesn't even exist), nor does it have a "type" to begin with, so we'll just remove that.

```
<form method="post">
            Select value:
            <select name="val">
            <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['val']) && $_POST['val'] == 1){ echo "selected";}?>>1</option><!-- check the posted value and compare it with option value and if equal then add selected attribute-->
            <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['val']) && $_POST['val'] == 2){ echo "selected";}?>>2</option>
            <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['val']) && $_POST['val'] == 3){ echo "selected";}?>>3</option>
            <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['val']) && $_POST['val'] == 4){ echo "selected";}?>>4</option>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="display"/>
            </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['val'])){ // check value is posted and set or not
        $val = $_POST['val'];
        echo($val);
    }
?>
```

Or more better:-

```
<form method="post">
    Select value:
    <select name="val">
    <?php 
    for($i =1;$i<=4;$i++){ // start loop
        if(isset($_POST['val']) && $_POST['val'] == $i){ // check posted value is set and equal to option or not if yes then add selected.
            echo "<option value=$i selected>$i</option>";
        }else{
            echo "<option value=$i >$i</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="display"/>
</form>         
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['val'])){ // check posted value is set or not
        $val = $_POST['val'];
        echo($val);
    }
?>
```

Note:- file extension must be `.php`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it helped! Number of options is fixed to 4 this time, although thanks for a suggestion. Could you perhaps explain how does it work that selected value stays on the list? I don't quite understand where it came from :)

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear now! Usage of 'for' loop might be more correct, but it makes a code a little harder to understand for me. Also, I understand everything now, thanks a lot for you help and effort!

Comment: May be hard to understand but correct practice to do  when data will come dynamically and you need to make select box on that data. Also currently if you want to increase option only increment in loop is enough.

Comment: `<select>` does not have a `type="integer"` ;-) it doesn't have a "type" to begin with.

Comment: Oh my goodness how it skipped from my eyes. Thanks @Fred-ii- . You saved me again from -ve marking

Comment: @Anant You're welcome. I made a slight edit to that effect ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Always appreciates your helpful nature without going angry

Comment: @Anant Believe me, he means well ;-)  Jay's a really nice guy you know :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes obviously. He always wants good for every one, but politeness is  missing sometimes. But never in you case.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Also frankly speaking i admire and follow him a lot after you.  because he always gives correct suggestions and codes like you.

Comment: @Anant I'm in no groups myself and doubt that Jay is in them neither. Other than Stack ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- LOL. Not interested in social life. No offence. I will have to restrict my self to follow you here only.